# Can I use node-inspector with meteor?

Tags: meteor, node-inspector

Can I use node-inspector with meteor?

I tried "--debug" option, and succeed to connect debug port.

But, cannot to access my codes.

> exec "$DEV_BUNDLE/bin/node" "--debug" "$METEOR" "$@"

Answer (score 0):

You might have countered the same problem like I have:

On Linux machine, Meteor script will spawn two processes:

- Process1: node "meteor files"
- Process2: node "your meteor files"

When you run `exec "$DEV_BUNDLE/bin/node" "--debug" "$METEOR" "$@"`, it spawn process1 in debug mode but process2 still run in normal mode. This is why you can not see your files.

I just run the regular meteor script and send `kill -s USR1` to process2 then you can see your file in node-inspector